# docker container start \ stop events

Tags: docker

Is there a docker log of container start and stop events?
(I am not interested in `docker logs` command, as that will give me the containers stdout log.)

There is of course the "status" field of the `docker ps` or `docker inspect` commands. but they will only give me the latest status of the container. I am searching for a more extended record of start \ stop events of the containers.

Answer (score 0):

`docker events` command gives the info I want.